# First row deleted on adding the second row in the JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JtextField and Jcombobox.Whenever values are selected from textfield and combobox and add button is clicked the values should appear in the table.The first row is added correctly.When i try to add the second row the first rows values are replaced with the new values but second row is not added.
Each time when add button is clicked values should be added to the table without deleting the older values and on click of delete i should be able to delete the row ..how can i achieve this.
Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
        {
        ModelSelection modelselection=new ModelSelection();
        modelselection.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

}

public ModelSelection() throws TooManyListenersException
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(240, 30, 906, 658);
    contentPane =new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    Image im=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/sprinkle.jpg")).getImage();
    setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(im)));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);                

    modelSelection=new JLabel("MODULE SELECTION");
    modelSelection.setBounds(240, 20, 450,40);
    modelSelection.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,40));
    Color modellabel = new Color(16,180,205);
    modelSelection.setForeground(modellabel);
    add(modelSelection);


    lab=new JLabel("Choose S-NET device and S-NET ID");
    lab.setBounds(30, 75, 500,40);
    lab.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25));
    Color label = new Color(176,224,230);
    lab.setForeground(label);
    add(lab);

    choice=new JLabel("S-Net Device    -");
    choice.setBounds(30, 145, 200, 20);
    choice.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25));
    Color choicecolor = new Color(135,206,250);
    choice.setForeground(choicecolor);      
    add(choice);

    String devicesnames[]={"SW-LE-4","SD-LD-4","SR-RL-8","SD-FL-4","SD-FN-2"};
    mod=new JComboBox(devicesnames);
    mod.setBounds(260,140,230,35);
    Color modcolor = new Color(173,216,230);
    mod.setBackground(modcolor);    
    mod.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,17));
    Color border=new Color(30,144,255);
    mod.setBorder(new LineBorder(border, 2));
    mod.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    add(mod);

    snet=new JLabel("S-Net ID            -");
    snet.setBounds(30, 200, 200, 20);
    snet.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25));
    Color snetcolor = new Color(135,206,250);
    snet.setForeground(snetcolor);      
    add(snet);  

    id=new JTextField("1");
    id.setBounds(260,200,230,35);
    id.setEditable(true);
    Color idcolor = new Color(173,216,230);
    id.setBackground(idcolor);  
    Color idborder=new Color(30,144,255);
    id.setBorder(new LineBorder(idborder, 3));
    id.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,20));
    add(id);

    validityid=new JLabel("**S-Net ID(1-230) only");
    validityid.setBounds(500, 210, 200, 20);
    validityid.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,18));
    Color validityidcolor = new Color(255,99,71);
    validityid.setForeground(validityidcolor);      
    add(validityid);    


    add=new JButton("ADD");
    add.setBounds(180,260, 80, 35);
    Color addbackground=new Color(0,0,255);
    add.setBackground(addbackground);           
    Color border1=new Color(30,144,255);
    add.setBorder(new LineBorder(border1,3));   
    add.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,18));
    add.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(mod.getSelectedItem()!=null && id.getText()!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("correct");
                simpleset();
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Fields cannot be empty", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("FAILURE");
                 dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                 dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
    add(add);

    devices=new JLabel("Selected S-NET device and S-NET ID");
    devices.setBounds(30, 310, 450,40);
    devices.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,25));
    Color deviceslabel = new Color(176,224,230);
    devices.setForeground(deviceslabel);
    add(devices);


    String columnNames[] = { "S-NET Device","S-NET ID"};
    String dataValues[][] =
    { 
        { "12", "234", },
        { "-123", "43",  },
        { "93", "89.2",  },
        { "12", "234", },
        { "-123", "43",  },


    };

    t=new JTable();
    JScrollPane s=new JScrollPane(t);
    s.setBounds(30, 360, 400, 200);
    Color sbcolor = new Color(128,200,242);
    t.setBackground(sbcolor);
    Color headercolor = new Color(152,252,252);
    t.getTableHeader().setBackground(headercolor);
    Color headerborder=new Color(0,0,255);
    t.getTableHeader().setBorder(new LineBorder(headerborder,2));
    t.getTableHeader().setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
    t.setRowHeight(30);
    t.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    t.setShowVerticalLines(true);
    t.setShowGrid(true);
    Color gridcolor=new Color(0,0,0);
    t.setGridColor(gridcolor);
    t.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 17));       
    Color scrollborder=new Color(15,132,210);
    s.setBorder(new LineBorder(scrollborder, 4));
    s.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    add(s);


    configure=new JButton("CONFIGURE");
    configure.setBounds(80,575, 120, 35);       
    Color configureborder=new Color(30,144,255);
    configure.setBorder(new LineBorder(configureborder, 3));
    Color configurebackground=new Color(50,205,50);
    configure.setBackground(configurebackground);
    configure.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15));
    configure.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    add(configure);
    delete=new JButton("DELETE");
    delete.setBounds(230,575, 120, 35);       
    Color deleteborder=new Color(30,144,255);
    delete.setBorder(new LineBorder(deleteborder, 3));
    Color deletebackground=new Color(220,20,60);
    delete.setBackground(deletebackground);
    delete.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15));
    delete.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    add(delete);



}   

protected void simpleset() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String data=mod.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println(data);

    String num=id.getText();


    String columnNames[] = { "S-NET Device","S-NET ID"};
    Object[][] row={{data,num}};
    for(int i=0;i<row.length;i++)
    {
    System.out.println(row[i]);
    }

     DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);   
     dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);    

     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

     list.add(num);
     list.add(data);

     dtm.addRow(list.toArray());

     t.setModel(dtm);             
    DefaultTableCellRenderer rightRenderer=new DefaultTableCellRenderer();                                             
    rightRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    t.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);
    t.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(rightRenderer);         



}
```

Comment: The text of a JTextField can be "", but it is never null.

Comment: @Maurice Perry  wrote `The text of a JTextField can be "", but it is never null.`, I'm sure that it can returns (JTextComponents) null, empty, value (e.g.) in String (char, any chars sequesnce, incl. whitespaces),

Comment: @mKorbel, as I said, it can be an empty string, not null.

Comment: @Maurice Perry Swing JComonents haven't any problem to hold and returns null value

Comment: @mKorbel well, if you setText(null), the null will be converted to an empty string, subsequence calls to getText() will return an empty string. So it would make a lot more sense to test if the id is not "" instead of testing if it is not null (it will never be).

Answer (score 2):

Your simpleset() recreates the TableModel on each call.

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
...
t.setModel(dtm);
```

Create it just once, store as a field (or obtain from the JTable instance) and use addRow() or insertRow() methods to insert new data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're recreating the whole table model each time the add button is clicked. The table model (as well as the table cell renderer, btw) must be created once at initialization, and you just need to call addRow when the button is clicked.